How to get a message from workbox-broadcast-update even if there is not update?
I'm trying workbox and service-worker for the first time today.
I'm using the stale-while-revalidate strategy with the BroadcastUpdatePlugin.
Everything works:

the browser starts a call

the Service Worker with Workbox return the cached response and starts a revalidation call

if the revalidation response is different I get a message! Great!


What I don't know is how to receive an event even if there is NO UPDATE from the revalidation call.
This is the code I'm using:
importScripts(
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/7.1.0/workbox-sw.js"
);

self.skipWaiting();

workbox.core.clientsClaim();

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.pathname.startsWith("/images/avatars/"),

  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    plugins: [new workbox.broadcastUpdate.BroadcastUpdatePlugin()],
  })
);

I would like something like this:
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.pathname.startsWith("/images/avatars/"),

  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    plugins: [new workbox.broadcastUpdate.BroadcastUpdatePlugin({
        callback: (response) => {
            if (response.isNew()) {
                const message = {};

                sendMessageToClient(message);
            }
        }
    })],
  })
);

Is there a way?
